# Knockout: doing a push into an observable array makes each item's computed observable to be executed

Tags: knockout.js

In the below code, i add an item to the observable array. This causes all the previous items to execute their computed observable when a .push is executed. This is unnecessary. How to prevent this?
The more items i have, it means that each items computed observable will be run.

See the fiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/k8kbdnnv/3/

html code

```
    <div id="logs"></div>
<table>  

<tbody data-bind="foreach: CompanySearchRows">
                <tr >
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind='textInput: ClientReference' type="text"  />

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind='textInput: CompanySearchReference' type="text"  />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
</table>
```

jscode

```
var viewModel;
var maxTitleRefRows = 50;

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.CompanySearchRows = new ko.observableArray([new ItemViewModel()]);
    self.Executions = ko.observable(0);

    self.addRow = function (clientReference) {  


    var newRow = new ItemViewModel();       

    self.CompanySearchRows.push(newRow);  //this causes the code to jump 

into each array item's OnCompanySearchReferenceChanged computed observable 
    };
}


function ItemViewModel() {
    var self = this;   
    self.ClientReference = ko.observable(""); 
    self.CompanySearchReference = ko.observable(""); 

self.OnCompanySearchReferenceChanged = ko.computed(function () {               
    var reference = self.CompanySearchReference();

   logIt("computed executed" + reference);


    if (reference !== ""  ) {                    
        var currentIndex = viewModel.CompanySearchRows.indexOf(self);
        viewModel.Executions(currentIndex);
        var length = viewModel.CompanySearchRows().length;
        var lastItemIndex = length - 1;   
        if (currentIndex === lastItemIndex && length < maxTitleRefRows ) {          
            viewModel.addRow(self.ClientReference());               
        }
    }

    return;
});      
}

var logs=document.getElementById('logs');
function logIt(msg){
    var e=document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML=msg;
    logs.insertBefore(e,logs.firstChild);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    
});
```

Comment: Your computed function contains a reference to the array. So if the array changes (e.g. a push) it triggers a recalculation of the all existing items.

    `var currentIndex = viewModel.CompanySearchRows.indexOf(self);`

I'm not quite clear on what the function is doing, so I can't recommend a change

Comment: Hmm, this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/162730): your `computed` is causing side effects and returns nothing sensible. Computed observables are for reading (and sometimes writing) a property on a view model.

Comment: Looking at the computed function, I assume that the item is trying determine if it's the last item in the array, and if it is, insert a new row? Is that right. If so you've probably got the logic in the wrong place: it's generally not good to have the child controlling the parent (I speak as a parent of three!). I'll see if I can create a better version where the main viewModel handles adding new rows, and the ItemViewModel can ignore it's array.

Comment: Yes thats what the computed is doing. If there is a change to the companySearchReference property then check if its the last row. If yes then insert new row into the parent array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `computed` function contains a reference to the `observableArray` in the main ViewModel. This means if the array changes (e.g. from a `push`) *all* the computed functions on all the items are re-evaluated.

Reading the code, it appears the intention of the computed function was to add a new row when a value was entered in the second field. So we only need to track the *last* item to do this. Doing this inside the child object is generally advised against - the main viewModel should manage the array, the child should be independent of it.

To achieve this, I used a [subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)  on the `CompanySearchReference` observable, but only on the last item. When this value changes, the parent ViewModel will add the new row, and also remove the subscription on the previous row, so there is only one subscription active at any point.

```
// subscribe to changes on the child's search reference
// when this has a value, create a new row
var subscription = newRow.CompanySearchReference.subscribe(function (newValue) {
   if (newValue && self.CompanySearchRows().length < maxTitleRefRows) {
       // value has been changed: first remove this subscription
       logIt("removing subscription");
       subscription.dispose();
       // add a new row (creates a new subscription on new row)
       logIt("adding new row");
       self.addRow();
   }
});
```

The full JSFiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/Quango/fgfw6Ld0/

Comment: I think your solution will work. It would have been good if there was a knockout function to stop any further executions.

Comment: You were using a computed value in the wrong way, so it's not really knockout's fault. Computed functions were not intended as temporary obnjects. A subscription (which can be turned off easily) is a more appropriate way to do this.